# Concatenate strings in a list

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I have a list like `l=['a', 'b', 'c']`
I want a String like 'abc'. So in fact the result is `l[0]+l[1]+l[2]`, which can also be writte as

```
s = ''
for i in l:
    s += i
```

Is there any way to do this more elegantly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
s = ''.join(l)
```

The string on which you call this is used as the delimiter between the strings in `l`:

```
>>> l=['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> ''.join(l)
'abc'
>>> '-'.join(l)
'a-b-c'
>>> ' - spam ham and eggs - '.join(l)
'a - spam ham and eggs - b - spam ham and eggs - c'
```

Using `str.join()` is *much* faster than concatenating your elements one by one, as that has to create a new string object for every concatenation. `str.join()` only has to create *one* new string object.

Note that `str.join()` will loop over the input sequence *twice*. Once to calculate how big the output string needs to be, and once again to build it. As a side-effect, that means that using a list comprehension instead of a generator expression is faster:

```
slower_gen_expr = ' - '.join('{}: {}'.format(key, value) for key, value in some_dict)
faster_list_comp = ' - '.join(['{}: {}'.format(key, value) for key, value in some_dict])
```

Comment: +1 Q/A offset of 25s pretty hard to match......

Comment: The Ninja strikes again.

Comment: A good link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join I like how this answer is so detailed for a really basic question

Comment: This is a lightning answer. Thanks! @jamylak: "really basic" is "really relative".

Comment: @Tengis Google searches are pretty easy, if I search your question title I find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850986/joining-elements-of-a-list-python , with this answer listed in the question description.

Comment: @jamylak: I have to disagree. I didn't new the function "join", so how could I google "join elements in Python?". I was thinking of it as a CONCATENATION-problem.

Comment: @Tengis I searched `"Concatenate elements of a list"`

Comment: @jamylak: Good for you. Better would be to be modest.

Comment: @Tengis alright sorry I didn't mean anything bad