# Formatting an unordered string in python

Tags: python, string, formatting

I am having a string like ...

```
"1" "2" "3" "4" " " "text1" "text2" "text3" "6" "first && second && third.." " " " 7 " "         8"..
```

What i Intended to achieve is...

```
 1,2,3,4,,text1,text2,text3,6,first && second && third..,,7,8,..
```

Can any one Help me with this ?

Comment: You mean you have a *list* of strings?

Comment: Yes Martijn Pieters .. It is a list of strings..

Comment: Is there a possibility of `,` appearing in the strings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate elements of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522362/concatenate-elements-of-a-list)

Comment: And Now we are talking abt the string but not a list

Comment: If this is a list, then the strings are *ordered*. Why did you completely change your question?

Comment: I rolled back your edit; the new version has little relation to the old, invalidating my answer entirely. If you have a new problem, ask a new question.

Comment: Write down the question as it is, if those values are within a list, then write them as a list of strings. We are not psychic...

Comment: K got the point. Can some one lift the downvotes so that i can ask questions in SO again ?

Comment: Please lift down votes.. I wanna ask questions again.. pleas ":(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a *list* of strings, then strip each element of whitespace and use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join these together with a delimiter:

```
','.join([s.strip() for s in list_of_strings])
```

Demo:

```
>>> list_of_strings = ["1", "2", "3", "4", " ", "text1", "text2", "text3", "6", "first && second && third..", " ", " 7 ", " "]
>>> ','.join([s.strip() for s in list_of_strings])
'1,2,3,4,,text1,text2,text3,6,first && second && third..,,7,'
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn Pieters it seems to be working fine with test data .. u are a life saver.. I shall check that on real data and will ask ur help if any thing goes wrong. :)

Comment: Martijn Peiters can u help me ?

Comment: Can some one lift the downvotes so that i can ask questions in SO again ?

Comment: I *already* helped you with the question; you didn't ask anything new. I cannot lift any downvotes because I didn't downvote.