# Append commas between variables

Tags: python, string

Following is my code. I want to append the ip:port string by a comma separated list.

```
ip = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']
memcache = ''
port = '11211'
for node in ip:
    memcache += str(node) + ':' + port
    # join this by comma but exclude last one
```

I want output in this format:

`memcache = 1.1.1.1:11211, 2.2.2.2:11211, 3.3.3.3:11211, 4.4.4.4:11211`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate elements of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522362/concatenate-elements-of-a-list)

Answer (score 5):

`memcache = ', '.join("{0}:{1}".format(ip_addr, port) for ip_addr in ip)`

Comment: You forgot the closing `"`.

Answer (score 4):

```
memcache = ', '.join(address + ':' + port for address in ip)
```

This uses the [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method to join strings with `', '` as a separator. A generator expression is used to append the port to each address; this could also be done with a list comprehension. (There's actually no performance benefit to the genexp in this context, but I prefer the syntax anyway.)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Indeed I did.

Answer (score 1):

```
memcache = ', '.join(address + ":" + port for address in ip)
```

best
Peter