# Pass elements of list as a separated string to django methods

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to pass list elements as a separated string to `value` mehtod. This is my main query:

```
resumes = JobRecord.objects.all().values('field1','field2','field3','field4')
```

Instead of writing the each field of my `JobRecord model` in the `values` method, I want to send this list `values` method:

```
fields_LIST =['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']
```

**How can I pass elements of list as a separated string to method ?**

**Hints**

I tested these solutions, but none of them responded:

**Vay 1:**

```
str(fields_LIST) # result: "['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']"
```

**Vay 2:**

```
str1 = ''
for item in fields_LIST:
    str1 += '\'' + item + '\'' + ',' # result: "'field1','field2','field3','field4',"
```

**Vay 3:**

pass list itself:

```
JobRecord.objects.all().values(fields_LIST) # result: Error :'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

**Vay 4:**

```
str1 = ','.join(str(e) for e in fields_LIST) # result: 'field1, field2, field3, field4'
```

**Studies** 
I did study this resource and questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559559/how-to-delete-a-character-from-a-string-using-python),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string),[3](https://www.decalage.info/en/python/print_list),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings),[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522362/concatenate-elements-of-a-list),[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906092/converting-a-list-to-a-string)

Comment: I can't understand the relevance of those links, or of versions 1, 2, and 4. What do those have to do with passing the list to the `values` method?

Comment: All of them are examples of how to turn list items into separate strings that need in our method @DanielRoseman

Comment: No they're not. They seem to be about joining list items into a single string.

Comment: Please pay more attention. Or put your links in my question @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `*`:

```
JobRecord.objects.all().values(*fields_LIST)
```