# Python, bringing two list elements together

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
['PHE', '45', 'HIS', '46', 'HIS', '46', 'HIS', '46', 'HIS', '46', 'HIS', '46']
```

I want it to turn into

```
['PHE 45', 'HIS '46', 'HIS '46'] # it goes on like that
```

how can I merge consecutive list elements to eachother?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850986/joining-pairs-of-elements-of-a-list-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension for instance..

```
out = [str(L1[i]) + " " + str(L1[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(L1)//2, 2)]
# Out[15]: ['PHE 45', 'HIS 46', 'HIS 46']
```