# List manipulation in Python - growing the elements' list

Tags: python, list

I define:

```
A = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

What is/are the line/s producing:

```
B = [['hello', [1, 2]], ['hello', [3, 4]], ['hello', [5, 6]]]
```

Comment: What have you tried, why did it fail?

Comment: `[['hello', i] for i in A]` ?

Answer (score 7):

You can add `'hello'` to the front of each list with a list comprehension:

```
>>> add = 'hello'
>>> A = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> [[add, x] for x in A]
[['hello', [1, 2]], ['hello', [3, 4]], ['hello', [5, 6]]]
# or [[add] + [x] for x in A]
```

Comment: I got my actual use case thanks to your answer + the zip function pointed by @VladimirPogosyan + this article: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850986/joining-pairs-of-elements-of-a-list-python)

Comment: @RobinTournemenne Feel free to accept an answer by clicking the green checkmark next to it if the problem has been solved! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This may be helpful:

```
B = zip(['hello'] * len(A), A)
```

This will produces following result: `[('hello', [1, 2]), ('hello', [3, 4]), ('hello', [5, 6])]`
If you need lists instead of tuples, you can use following code:

```
B = list(map(list, zip(['hello'] * len(A), A)))
```